# Rate limiting API call for specific users on cloud endpoints

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-run, rate-limiting

I have an API that deployed on Google Cloud Run. Then for security, I use Google Cloud Endpoints as the Gateway. As long as I know, Cloud Endpoints has a rate limiting feature by setting it in the OpenAPI config but it can be specified which user I want to assign the limit to. Is there any other solutions? Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to [Cloud Endpoint quotas](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/quotas-overview)? You can check these documentation on configuring quotas [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/quotas-configure) and [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/rate-limit-your-api-usage-with-cloud-endpoints-quotas-1270da55d2bf).

Comment: @RobertG I have read your suggestion, but it said that I should create another project because Cloud Endpoints used the project number for the quota limit. is there any other way to give a different quotas for each user?

Comment: Your correct that Cloud Endpoints enforces quotas through (Consumer) Projects (or Orgs). This matches how Google publishes its services e.g. Cloud Endpoints itself. Your Project using Cloud Endpoints is the Consumer Project for Google's service. It's unclear what you mean by "user" but, Cloud Endpoints doesn't provide a good mechanism for rate limiting by human end-users. You would need to create Projects and API Keys for end-users which is problematic.

Comment: Cloud Armor is a service that may be more suitable. I've not used it. It enables [rate limiting](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rate-limiting-overview#integration_with) though not by identities (!?) but by clients (IP, request metadata etc.).

Comment: @ferdianm10, does DazWilkin's suggestion answer your question? If so, please post it as an answer so that it would be helpful for other community members with similar questions as yours.